# Put div in center

Tags: css

I have a problem. This is my code:

```
<body>
    <div class="imerologio">
        <div id="imerologio-mistika">    
            <a href="foo"><img src="#"></a>
        </div>

        <div id="imerologio-xarti">    
            <a href="foo"><img src="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my css is:

```
.imerologio{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

#imerologio-mistika{
    background: url("../images/imerologio/mistika.png") no-repeat;
    float:left;
}

#imerologio-xarti{
    background: url("../images/imerologio/xarti.png") no-repeat;
    float:left;
}
```

I wand to center the inside divs, but i can't. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove floats, set `display: inline-block` to items and `text-align: center` to container.

```css
.imerologio {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
#imerologio-mistika {
  background: url("../images/imerologio/mistika.png") no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
#imerologio-xarti {
  background: url("../images/imerologio/xarti.png") no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="imerologio">
  <div id="imerologio-mistika">
    <a href="foo">
      <img src="#">
    </a>
  </div><!--

  --><div id="imerologio-xarti">
    <a href="foo">
      <img src="#">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, but if i want these images flat to width?

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: If i add an inside div the three images are located to the center and there is a big space on the left and on the right. I want these three images flat to the width of background.